# undefined variable being returned by JavaScript for unforeseen reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parse-platform

I'm using JavaScript and parse.com

The below code is not returning any errors in the console log and is creating a new object in parse.com as expected (Under myBadges). But for some reason "BadgeName" is not being captured and is showing as "undefined".

The "BadgeName" column should be populated from the "badgeselected" variable. But "BadgeName" does not appear to being captured as a variable?

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Here is a screen shot of the parse.com backend.

[image]

```
var badgeselected = $("#go").attr("src"); 
    var MyBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
    var userbadges = new MyBadges();

    $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#send").click(function () {
                   userbadges.set("BadgeName", badgeselected);
                         console.log("done");

                    userbadges.save(null, {
                        success: function (results) {
                            // The object was saved successfully.
                            location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (contact, error) {
                            // The save failed.
                            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line, `var badgeselected = $("#go").attr("src");`, must also exist inside the `$(document).ready` callback.

The entire point of that callback is to ensure that the DOM is ready for you to access it. You've put *some* of your DOM-accessing code inside the callback, but not all of it.

Comment: I've also made a stupid mistake that is'nt seen in the code above. basically I was trying to call a id for "Go" where infact its defined as a class. Changing this and the above answer from @meagar has resolved this issue.